# Responsive design: slow internet communication vs. high frequency of user interactions

Tags: ios, core-data, responsive-design

Sometimes operations are depending on each other, user can not update record until he inserted it. How can client changes be synchronised / uploaded to server, without blocking the GUI, if user interactions are more frequent than internet communication allows it?

In my recent version of my app, I store changes in Core Data and same time send change to backend, and until success message returns, I block GUI to keep client and server storage in a consistent state. But I know it is not a good approach especially if there is a lot of control in the same GUI, and user could play with them manipulate them quickly with short delays. Because it is annoying, that you have to wait.

What general approach do you recommend to build a responsive app which is not depending and able to hide the relative slowness of internet communication. Any good tutorial about it?

This is a theoretic question, and expecting theoretic answer.

Comment: One approach is to add a save button. when the user finishes changes you save send them to server.

Comment: 2nd approach, don't block GUI and when user changes another thing cancel current connection and create another one with all the changes

Comment: note that if your changes includes switching flags on and off as boolean. don't do a switch api. do a set api that sets the value to true or false. not reversing as n=!n

Comment: Is these changes critical or you can wait for an hour or so to send it to server?

Comment: like a chat message, not critical, but you expect an ASAP answer

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to have this setup with parent and child managed object contexts:

```
SavingContext (background, saves to persistent store)
MainContext (main thread, child context of saving context)
WorkerContext (background, child context of main context)
```

*Thanks Marcus Zarra.*

UI initiated changes in the model get saved right away in the main context. You then send them to the backend in a spawned worker context. You can have several of these without problem.

Once the response comes from the server, you save the changes in the worker context which "pushes" them up to the main context. Here you can define a merge policy that resolves any conflicts (for details please ask a new question).

The main context can now update the UI with the new information (if any).

Comment: why do you "push" to main context, if change is already in main context? or you save up to persistent store too? but what if some of the changes are ok, some of them were cancelled?

Comment: "Pushing" is how the "save" of a child context works. It just tells its parent and does not "save" to the persistent store. You are right: theoretically, if everything goes well, the worker context just confirms that everything is synced with the server, so the main context can perhaps record this and does not have to make UI changes. But if there is some discrepancy, the main context can react in an appropriate way.

Comment: Is closing the app by user can stop the worker context?

Comment: Yep. You an do any cleanups in `applicationWillTerminate`.